# Can monsters use the mystic slide

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

Can monsters use the mystic slide? In one of the rooms we had the slide that leads to the basement. The haunt was the one where the betrayer controls one zombie-lord and many zombies.

How we played it:
When a zombie enters the room with the slide, they can go to any room they choose from the basement. The heroes themselves played as normal - they roll dice in order to use the slide. Is this correct?

Comment: Some of this will depend on which haunt you get.

Comment: Thank you! I will separate them in different posts. Here I will only leave the first question. The haunt is where the betrayal controls one zombie lord and many zombies (I do not know if there are other haunts like this, we only played 2 haunts). Also are there any policies not to spoil?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, monsters can use any special room as they want.*

From [the rulebook](https://www.fgbradleys.com/rules/rules2/BetrayalAtTheHouseOnTheHill-rules.pdf):

> Like traitors, monsters can ignore all nondamaging room features. They can use the Coal Chute, Collapsed Room, Gallery, Mystic Elevator, and stairs tiles, along with many of the special movement options described on cards (such as
>   the Secret Stairs), unless those cards say that only explorers can use them. They ignore the effect of the Furnace Room and the Crypt.

And the [official FAQ](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/ah/FAQ_BHotH_102605-2.pdf):

> Can monsters use the Secret Stairs, Secret Passage, Revolving Wall, and Mystic Slide to
>   move around?
>
> > Yes. It's their house, after all. (Besides, it's possible for these to create areas of the house that can't be reached any other way, and some scenarios won't work if monsters can't reach all rooms.) Ignore the section of the rules that states, "unless those cards state that only explorers can use them." Also, a monster wouldn't need to roll to use the revolving wall.

*Note that this does not include stat-gaining rooms such as Chapel, Gymnasium, Larder, and Library. From the FAQ:

> Chapel, Gymnasium, Larder, Library -- Can monsters use these rooms?
>
> > No. Unless a monster is actually a transformed traitor (a werewolf, for instance), its attributes usually do not change.